# Compilation and execution when code is not dislosed; use of ellipsis in code

Tags: c++

In an interview I was asked following question

Given the code fragments below, where the ellipsis (…) represents code that has not been disclosed to you:

```
class X { … };  class Y { public: explicit Y(const X& x); … };
```

what can you say about the compilation and execution of each of the following statements?  Describe each of the operations that occur as this code executes.

```
Y func(Y y) { … }
X x;
Y y = func(Y(x));
```

I could not understand the question properly hence was not able to answer. if some one could explain me what answer was expected of me or share any link which I can go through, that would be really nice. Many Thanks.

Comment: The ellipsis in this case probably means that the undisclosed parts are irrelevant.

Comment: Ellipses are valid in C++ for variadic functions ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic ) and C++11 variadic templates ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template ).  But that's not what they mean here.  In this case they mean "assume everything not on the paper is irrelevant to the question."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `...` means that there could be some code, which could affect the compilation and execution of code?

What is happening in code:

- `X` default ctor is called,
- `func(Y(x))` is called: `Y(x)` ctor is explicitly called to create Y object from `x`.

Compilation of code depends (among other things) on `X` and `Y` constructors, ex.:

- adding private default ctor to `X` prevents code from compilation,
- adding private copy ctor to `Y` prevents code from compilation.

Answer (score 1):

The line `Y func(Y y) { … }` can work only if `Y` has at least copy or move constructor, because otherwise you have no way of returning from the function or passing the parameter into it.

`X x` will only work if `X` has a default constructor.

`Y y = func(Y(x));` will again only work if `Y` has copy or move constructor.

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9be2989558676023) is an example.